# Ruby/Rails: converting a Date to a UNIX timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, timestamp

How would I get a UNIX timestamp (number of seconds since 1970 GMT) from a Date object in a Rails app?

I know `Time#to_i` returns a timestamp, but doing `Date#to_time` and then getting the timestamp results in something that's off by about a month (not sure why...).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: OK, I think I figured it out- I was processing a date several times in a loop, and each time the date was moved a little because of a time zone mismatch, ultimately leading to my timestamp being a month off. Still, I'd be interested in knowing if there's any way to do this without relying on `Date#to_time`.

Answer (score 391, accepted):

The code `date.to_time.to_i` should work fine.  The Rails console session below shows an example:

```
>> Date.new(2009,11,26).to_time
=> Thu Nov 26 00:00:00 -0800 2009
>> Date.new(2009,11,26).to_time.to_i
=> 1259222400
>> Time.at(1259222400)
=> Thu Nov 26 00:00:00 -0800 2009
```

Note that the intermediate DateTime object is in local time, so the timestamp might be several hours off from what you expect.  If you want to work in UTC time, you can use DateTime's method "utc".

Comment: DateTime doesn't have `to_utc`

Comment: `date.to_time.utc` is probably what he meant.

Comment: In Rails, through ActiveSupport, a DateTime instance does have a utc() method (also aliased to getutc)

Answer (score 85):

I get the following when I try it:

```
>> Date.today.to_time.to_i
=> 1259244000
>> Time.now.to_i
=> 1259275709
```

The difference between these two numbers is due to the fact that `Date` does not store the hours, minutes or seconds of the current time. Converting a `Date` to a `Time` will result in that day, midnight.

Comment: ... "will result in that day, midnight." __in the system time zone__ where it is ran, which makes it not very portable as this information is not included/implied by the value. Anyone who uses this solution to persist or expose the value, should probably convert it to UTC first.

Answer (score 12):

Solution for Ruby 1.8 when you have an arbitrary DateTime object:

```
1.8.7-p374 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
1.8.7-p374 :002 > DateTime.new(2012, 1, 15).strftime('%s')
 => "1326585600"
```

Answer (score 10):

The suggested options of using `to_utc` or `utc` to fix the local time offset does not work. For me I found using `Time.utc()` worked correctly and the code involves less steps:

```
> Time.utc(2016, 12, 25).to_i
=> 1482624000 # correct
```

vs

```
> Date.new(2016, 12, 25).to_time.utc.to_i
=> 1482584400 # incorrect
```

---

Here is what happens when you call utc after using `Date`....

```
> Date.new(2016, 12, 25).to_time
=> 2016-12-25 00:00:00 +1100 # This will use your system's time offset
> Date.new(2016, 12, 25).to_time.utc
=> 2016-12-24 13:00:00 UTC
```

...so clearly calling `to_i` is going to give the wrong timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.new(2012, 1, 15).to_time.to_i
```