# Convert Ruby Date to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date

How can I convert a Ruby Date to an integer?

Comment: What should this integer represent?

Comment: I need to display a graph. So I want to scale the dates. MinDate will be zero. Max date will be 100

Comment: Then, as shown in my solution, simply subtract two `Date` objects to get the number of days between them. If you actually mean date/timestamps, you can also subtract `Time` objects (in which case you get the number of seconds between them, or you can use `DateTime` objects (which yield fractional days between instances).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby/Rails: converting a Date to a UNIX timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805950/ruby-rails-converting-a-date-to-a-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Date cannot directly become an integer. Ex:

```
$ Date.today
=> #<Date: 2017-12-29 ((2458117j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
$ Date.today.to_i
=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_i' for #<Date: 2017-12-29 ((2458117j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Your options are either to turn the Date into a time then an Int which will give you the seconds since epoch:

```
$ Date.today.to_time.to_i
=> 1514523600
```

Or come up with some other number you want like days since epoch:

```
$ Date.today.to_time.to_i / (60 * 60 * 24)  ### Number of seconds in a day
=> 17529   ### Number of days since epoch
```

Comment: This is simply not true, Ruby has native support to convert from and to `jd` since 1.9.3

Answer (score 95):

```
t = Time.now
# => 2010-12-20 11:20:31 -0700

# Seconds since epoch
t.to_i
#=> 1292869231

require 'date'
d = Date.today
#=> #<Date: 2010-12-20 (4911101/2,0,2299161)>

epoch = Date.new(1970,1,1)
#=> #<Date: 1970-01-01 (4881175/2,0,2299161)>

d - epoch
#=> (14963/1)

# Days since epoch
(d - epoch).to_i
#=> 14963

# Seconds since epoch
d.to_time.to_i
#=> 1292828400
```

Comment: I don't see `to_time` in the core doc: http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html until Ruby 1.9.2 (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html). At that point, you can just use `to_i`.

Comment: Is there a solution for Ruby 1.8.*?

Comment: @JellicleCat What do you need? Converting Ruby Date to Time? Getting number of days since epoch? Getting number of seconds since epoch?

Comment: Seconds since epoch.  I know I could do `Time.utc(date.year, date.month, date.day)`.  I was hoping for something more elegant looking.

Comment: Your Seconds since epoch example is wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4492607/432 instead.

Comment: @superjoe30 Your link goes to this page. Can you clarify why you believe that it is wrong?

Comment: The link is a link to EnabrenTane's answer on this same page. I didn't see the first example you gave with `Time.now.to_i` which is the answer I was looking for. Instead I saw your comment that said seconds since epoch with the expression `Date.today.to_time.to_i` which does not update every second. tl;dr: your answer is correct but unclear if not read carefully.

Comment: @superjoe30 Thanks for the comment; I will clarify my answer. Note that if the user has a `Date` instance—not a `Time` or `DateTime`—then the integer seconds will never increase every second.

Answer (score 12):

```
Time.now.to_i
```

returns seconds since epoch format

Comment: I'm starting with a date object not a time object

Comment: You can convert a `Date` object to a `Time` object using `my_date.to_time`

Comment: Be warned that `to_time` will use the system time zone, so you probably want to be explicit: `my_date.to_time(:utc).to_i`.

Comment: One of the reasons why you'd work with Dates is to circumvent this problem. Using `Date#jd` would be a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

Solution for Ruby 1.8 when you have an arbitrary `DateTime` object:

```
1.8.7-p374 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
1.8.7-p374 :002 > DateTime.new(2012, 1, 15).strftime('%s')
 => "1326585600"
```

Comment: Token +1, but you know, Ruby 1.8 will soon be dead.

Comment: As long as there are still 1.8 applications that do their job I'm not convinced :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm incredibly surprised that nobody has given what I believe to be the most correct answer to this.

Since Ruby 1.9.3, Dates can be converted from and to integers. To get the julian day number for any Date, simply use:

```rb
> Date.today.jd
 => 2460011

> Date.jd(2460011)
 => Tue, 07 Mar 2023
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it recently and took some time to figure it out but that is how I came across a solution and it may give you some ideas:

```
require 'date'
today = Date.today

year = today.year
month = today.mon
day = day.mday

year = year.to_s

month = month.to_s

day = day.to_s    


if month.length <2
  month = "0" + month
end

if day.length <2
  day = "0" + day
end

today = year + month + day

today = today.to_i

puts today
```

At the date of this post, It will put 20191205.

In case the month or day is less than 2 digits it will add a 0 on the left.

I did like this because I had to compare the current date whit some data that came from a DB in this format and as an integer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: This is a great solution, however, the numers it produces wouldn't scale very well. Due to the fact months are 1-12 and days are 1-30. There would be gaps in the ranges.