# How to compare created_at in Rails with timezones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method in my application:

```
  def self.for_today
    where("log_entries.created_at > ?", Time.zone.today)
  end
```

`log_entries.for_today`

```
Time.zone: GMT-08:00) Tijuana 
Time.now.in_time_zone: 2013-07-30 19:21:54 -0700 
[#<LogEntry id: 67,  created_at: "2013-08-01 03:11:55", updated_at: "2013-07-31 02:19:26", user_id: 1>,
 #<LogEntry id: 68, created_at: "2013-07-31 20:12:24", updated_at: "2013-07-31 02:19:26", user_id: 1>, 
 #<LogEntry id: 69, created_at: "2013-07-31 02:19:26", updated_at: "2013-07-31 02:19:26", >]
```

Those log entries still show up as today even though the date clearly differs.

Unfortunately this doesn't actually reference today as it's going off of purely UTC.

If a user sets their timezone, something that they recorded yesterday could still show up today.

How do I fix this?

Comment: [Convert to epoch time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492557/convert-ruby-date-to-integer) and compare those, at that stage, timezones are irrelevant.

Comment: How do I do that as a class method for sorting?

Answer (score -1):

Timezone thing rails handles at application level. In database records are going to be saved according to your database timezone.

And can handle this timezone thing at application level.

Show some method or code where exactly you are getting wrong records or having problem.

Comment: The issue is what I describe above. I'm trying to display a list of log entries for today, but it's showing them from yesterday too. I want it to display from current user's timezone 12am on wards.