# Rails - How to display number of days between two dates in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a simple rails app and I have a form whereby the employee can register vacation days. I have two date fields (`start_date` and `end_date`), and I would like to have a field that is displayed in the`show` action/page (and if possible to appear instantaneously within the form itself after the days are selected). How can I do this?

Comment: You can subtract Ruby Date objects from each other to get the difference in days. As for showing things instantly, you're going to have to use some JavaScript, AJAX and a partial. You can search on Stack Overflow and the internet for "rails dynamic view update" or something like that. And this is how to display an elephant in a Rails form: ~:3

Answer (score 0):

This is how can you do it in the ruby.

```
(start_date.to_i - end_date.to_i) / 86_400
```

`DateTime.to_i` returns [seconds since epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4492604/2926641)

86400 - amount of the seconds in day.

Just add AJAX query or some another async code as simplest solution.