# Sort entries by combination of rating and date

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I have a bunch of entries with its rating and creation date. Could you please give me a hint, how can I sort it by combination of recentness and rating, so an entry with rating 50 will be near an entry with rating 100 from last year?

Comment: You need to provide sample data and an explanation of the ordering that you intend.  Such an ordering is very subjective.

Comment: Share your efforts you did to get the expected output.

Comment: Convert date to integer and multiply by rating (weighting the factors) to get a coefficient to be used for sorting. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492557/convert-ruby-date-to-integer

Answer (score 0):

If you will add an ORDER by CREATION_DATE DESC, RATING DESC then the result will be like this:

2019-01-04 100

2019-01-04  99

2018-12-30 150

2019-12-12 130

Hope this helps.