# yyyy-mm-dd to timestamps in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Rails App where I want to convert some database entries to timestamps. Trouble is that they are in the format yyyy-mm-dd which gives this wrong timestamp:

```
irb(main):005:0> Date.new(2014-05-14).to_time.to_i * 1000
=> 788914800000
```

Instead I want something like this:

```
irb(main):006:0> Date.new(2014,05,14).to_time.to_i * 1000
=> 1400018400000
```

So how do I go about doing that in Ruby?

I've looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805950/ruby-rails-converting-a-date-to-a-unix-timestamp), but although helpful, it doesn't really solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Date.parse` instead of `Date.new`

```
Date.parse('2014-05-14').to_time.to_i * 1000
```

When `Date.new` is called with **2014-05-14** it mean that it is being passed **1995** as an year, hence the wrong timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Time.parse`...

```
database_entry = '2014-05-14'
Time.parse(database_entry)
=> => 2014-05-14 00:00:00 +0100
```

Comment: That is a neat solution. Thank you!