# Convert from format date string to unix (epoch) time value

Tags: ruby, time

How can I convert from a formatted time string (e.g. 3/17/98) to a Unix time stamp (i.e. num. seconds from Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00)?

I can find many methods of converting into a date string in the Ruby "date" library, but none to go back the other way. While this won't be a problem in later builds, my proof of concept application is using a SQLite database which does not support the "DATE" type format.

Comment: What is the format used in `3/17/98`?

Comment: Apologies for the delay.  Illness.

The date format is m/d/yy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the string into an array of integers, look into `split('/')`, to turn that into a unix time stamp look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805950/ruby-rails-converting-a-date-to-a-unix-timestamp) (you probably want `to_i` but be warned that it incorporates your local time zone).